# Add custom user data to matplotlib artist

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an PyQt5 based GUI with embedded matplotlib canvas.  The GUI is for general data exploration of 1 or more data sets.   It lets users add/remove line plots to however many subplots they want with left/right twinx axes.

Keeping track of all the metadata (source data file, variable name, etc.) associated with each line on each of the axes is a bit tedious.  It would be nice to attach some custom metadata directly to the line artist object.   This would be something like Matlab's `UserData` property of handle graphic objects.

One of my main use cases for this would be context menu's on each line. I could pull information directly from the picked artist's user data instead of having to maintain some kind of dictionary of line objects to metadata.

So my questions are:

- I have done this and so far seems to be ok ... But is adding
  attributes to Matplotlib artists a terrible idea for some reason I'm
  not aware of?
- Is there already some user definable meta data container in an artist
  that I am just not aware of (couldn't find anything in the docs)?
- Is it really as simple as something like this?

Example:

```
lines = ax.plot([1,2,3])
lines[0].user_data = {'some':'info', 'about':'this_line'}

#... elsewhere in pick_event or button_press_event
my_lines = ax.lines
user_data = my_lines[0].user_data
#... do something useful with this info ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to attach a custom attribute to a python object. The only thing to be aware of is that it should in no case conflict with existing attributes. `user_data` is not currently an existing attribute of `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`, or in fact any other matplotlib artist.
Hence the only risk is that in some future version, matplotlib may introduce an attribute with the name you chose. I can't see this happening, but it's a more general thing to consider.

If you want an alternative, artist have a [`gid`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_gid.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_gid) parameter. If you hold a mapping of `gid` to your data, you could use it like

```
user_data = {"1" : {'some':'info', 'about':'this_line'},
             "2" : {'some':'other info', 'about':'that_line'}}

line, = plt.plot(...)
line.set_gid("1")

line_data = user_data[line.get_gid()]
```